# c++ can't get selection sort to work properly

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

I am trying to understand sorting algorithms, so based on googled examples/explanations I wrote the below code. Code works 80% of the time. Every once in a while it doesn't sort properly and I can not see why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void setArray( int *, const int & );
void selectionSorting( int *, const int & );

int main()
{
    int numOfElem;
    cout << "Num of array elements: ";
    cin >> numOfElem;
    cout << '\n';

    int array[numOfElem];
    setArray(array, numOfElem);

    selectionSorting(array, numOfElem);

    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}

void setArray( int *array, const int & numOfElem ){
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "Original array: " << '\n';
    for (int i=0; i<numOfElem; i++){
        array[i] = rand()%30;
        cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

void selectionSorting( int *array, const int &numOfElem ){
    int eff_size, swap;
    int maxpos = 0;
    for (eff_size = numOfElem; eff_size>1; eff_size--){
        // loop searching for a position of largest number in the array
        for (int i=0; i<eff_size; i++){
            maxpos = array[i] > array[maxpos] ? i : maxpos;
        }
        swap = array[maxpos];
        array[maxpos] = array[eff_size-1];
        array[eff_size-1] = swap;
    }
    cout << "Selection Sorting: " << '\n';
    for (int i=0; i<numOfElem; i++){
        cout << array[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Num of array elements: 5

Original array:
7 17 1 12 25
Selection Sorting:
1 7 17 25 12
```

I can't see any pattern to the sorting failing - it fails in different places, weather there are repeated numbers, regardless of how many numbers I provide etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On each iteration of the outer loop(over `eff_size`) you should re-set `maxpos` to 0. Otherwise you have the chance that `maxpos` goes out of the effective portion being sorted(this happens if the maximum element is last in the effective portion i.e. if `maxpos==effsize`).

Comment: Actually, as the array gets partially sorted over each iteration, `maxpos` could be set to the index of the current element of the iteration, right? Not that it would bring much performance gains in this case anyway...

Comment: @Streppel there are enough threads on how selection sort can be optimized. My answer is focused on the problem in the implementation presented in the question

Comment: Ahhh... I spent 2h trying to resolve this small issue. Works perfectly now - Thanks a lot! (I'd give +1 if I had enough rep!)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev sure, I wasn't trying to be "that guy", just pointed it out. :-) sorry

Comment: @tx1131 please see [What does it mean when an answer is 'accepted'?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that you can reward Ivaylo for his answer